# Is it possible to add jax-ws server-side handlers that execute *before* WS-Security processing?

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, cxf, jax-ws, ws-security

What I want a a way to manipulate the message context before it reaches the WS-Security engine (usually wss4j) in order to dinamically change the required policy, crypto properties, etc.

Based on my tests, handlers defined via handler chains are executed after initial processing/dispatching by the jax-ws stack, so it´s too late.

I´d rather not reinvent the weel by moving all WS-Security processing to application-defined handlers, but this seems to be the only viable alternative that does not require fiddling with the stack itself.